# Cannot change file ownership from bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run the command

```
chown -R "$USER" /mnt/namenode
```

from a bash script to change the ownership of the namenode folder and its sub-folders. When I type the command manually

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /mnt/namenode
```

it works, but not when I do it from the script. From the script, only the ownership of the namenode is changing, not its subfolders. Does anyone know how I might fix this?

OK, I got it. My script was formatting the namenode after the ownership had been set. Before the format, the subfolders has the correct ownership recursively. After the format, the sub-folders' ownership was changing to root. So I made the following change:

```
echo 'Y' | /home/$USER/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop namenode -format
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/namenode
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/datanode
```

In other words, I set the ownership after I did the formatting.

Comment: Are you sure $USER has the right value? Insert an `echo $USER` before the `chown`

Comment: this command works well for me `sudo chown -R ubuntu /mnt/namenode` .....  it is possible that the disc is write-protected ?

Comment: My tip is, that your `$USER` variable is wrong. Echo it to make sure what is its content.

Comment: No, $USER is showing correctly. In any case, the ownership of the namenode folder is correct, so the variable name was not a problem. It's just that recursively it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/namenode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script with `sudo` (as you are doing), inside the script `$USER` will be `root` not the normal user.
So use `sudo` **inside** the script:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" /mnt/namenode
```

and run the script without `sudo`.

Comment: $USER is shown as ubuntu. Besides, I have to run the script as sudo because of some commands which require higher privileges.

Comment: have you tried `echo $USER` inside the script? It should show `root`. And are you in a live dvd ?

Comment: It's showing ubuntu. No, i am not using any dvd. It's a virtual machine with ubuntu running.

Comment: It's awkward, may be other things in your script affecting the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem.

Try to add the slash at the end of folder as:

```
chown -R "$USER" /mnt/namenode/
```